# mvc3 use entity to update many database records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, updates

I am trying to use entity to update many records up to 30 if the conditions inside the statement match but i am having an issue finding the correct method to use at the end what I have is this

```
public ActionResult Edit(profile profile)
{
  //change all records where getid== x.registrationID
  var getprofile =
    (from x in db.Articles where getid == x.RegistrationID select x).Any();

  getprofile.firstname = profile.firstname;
  getprofile.lastname = profile.lastname;
}
```

The error i get is on `getprofile.firstname` and `getprofile.lastname` saying the `bool` does not contain a definition for `firstname` or `lastname`. If i put in `FirstorDefault()` everything works fine but of course it only changes the 1st record...

How can I change many records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ToList()` to get a collection of `Articles`:

```
List<Article> getprofiles = ( from x in db.Articles ... ).ToList();

foreach( Article getprofile in getprofiles )
{
  getprofile.firstname = profile.firstname;
  getprofile.lastname = profile.lastname;
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

This queries the database, gets the matching `Article` rows and puts them in a collection - a `List<Article>`

You can then modify the objects in the collection and finally call `db.SaveChanges()` to update the database.

Comment: +1,  .any() returns bool so you cant edit the result.  it tells you there were matching records yes or no.  Get a list of matching records, edit the list and save result.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var objRD = objBS.Articles.Where(c => c.RegistratinID.Equals(getID));

        if (objRD.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (ReportingData objR in objRD)
            {
                objR.firstname = profile.firstname;
                objR.lastname = profile.lastname;

            }
        }
        objBS.SaveChanges();
```